# can you return a value from a thread in c when using semaphores

Tags: c, pthreads, semaphore

I have a c program that creates a thread when it starts. The purpose of the thread is to flash firmware to a device when instructed to do so. So the when the thread starts it waits on a semaphore and a some point the main application will `sem_post(&semaphore);` post to the semaphore in the thread and the thread will complete its task.

Sometimes this task can fail (if there is a hardware issue). My question is can I return a value from the thread to where the semaphore was posted to in the main application? The flashing of the firmware is done with a `system()` and the result is returned to the int variable `res`. I want to return this value to main application?

Here is the thread:

```
static void *flash_firmware(void *param) {

    int res;
    char thread_Buf[SM_BUF];

    printf("Started thread\r\n");

    while(running == 1) {

        sem_wait(&semaphore);

        if(running == 1) {
            printf("*************Flashing firmware*************\r\n");
            snprintf(thread_Buf, SM_BUF, prog_path_printf,
                    programmingPtr->binary_filename, programmingPtr->debugger_serialnumber);

            res = system(thread_Buf); //flash firmware

        }
        else
            printf("Exiting thread \r\n");

    }

    return NULL;

}
```

Here is a snippet of `main()` where I create the threads.

```
#define THREADS 2
pthread_t thread_ID [THREADS];

int volatile running = 1;
sem_t semaphore;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

/initialize semaphores to be used with threads in this process, set value to 0 initially
    sem_init(&semaphore, 0, 0);


    //create threads for DUTs 1 & 3
    pthread_create(&thread_ID[0], NULL, flash_firmware, &programmingPtr);

}
```

Then in a different source file, `sem_post(&semaphore);` will be executed and the thread will proceed.

Comment: You can do this with any form of IPC, a pipe, a mailbox, a socket, you chose. Have main either wait or poll the IPC for the result from the thread. There are surely other ways too.

Comment: Undefined behavior for unsynchronized, non-readonly, non atomic access to an object from multiple threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

You can return a pointer to your desired return value with [pthread_exit()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html), and than catch it later with [calling pthread_join()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html).

Just be sure that the pointer is referencing a static or an allocated memory location.

You may also use the pointer as an integer if it is enough information for you, example:

```
pthread_exit((void *)0);

int ret;
pthread_join(tid , (void **)&ret);
```

Comment: Undefined behavior for accessing an object through an lvalue expression not of the effective type of the object or a character type.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the `programmingPtr` structure argument passed to Thread, but by adding one more `result` variable to that structure and update that in the `flash_firmware` thread based on the your conditions. on return from the thread, observe the value of `result` in the main function like below:

let's have one more element in your existing `programmingPtr` structure

```
struct programmingPtr{
    int result;
};
```